# Most efficient row multiplication with matrix in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix as such

```
df = pd.DataFrame(randint(2,size=(3,9)))
df.values
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Again; each row in this example represents three 3D coordinates, that need to rotated by, e.g. the following rotation matrix:

```
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]])
```

To do this as efficiently as possible (the real problem has millions of coordinates btw) currently, I am somewhat baffled that I have to do:

First apply `df.reshape` - each row in this example consists of three 3D coordinates as so [(x,y,z),(x,y,z),(x,y,z)]:

```
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

Then in order to get it to [rotate to convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), one must take `u_new = R \dot u` which means the transpose of the above, so that we can take a column-wise (i.e. coordinate) multiplication with the rotation matrix.

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Then we can do the multiplication:

```
pd.DataFrame(dot(rotmat,df)).values

array([[  0.00e+00,   2.22e-16,   0.00e+00,   1.00e+00,   2.22e-16,
          2.22e-16,   1.00e+00,   1.00e+00,   2.22e-16],
       [  1.00e+00,   0.00e+00,   1.00e+00,   1.00e+00,   1.00e+00,
          1.00e+00,   0.00e+00,   0.00e+00,   1.00e+00],
       [  0.00e+00,  -1.00e+00,   0.00e+00,  -1.00e+00,  -1.00e+00,
         -1.00e+00,   2.22e-16,  -1.00e+00,  -1.00e+00]])
```

And then reverse the whole process to get this back into the original shape, to be used for other purposes.

Surely there must be more efficient ways to do this (hopefully without messing with the rotation matrix)?

Comment: I'd recommend you use numpy to deal with geometric transformations instead pandas, take a look to this [library](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html). In fact, if you're looking for speed, transfer the data to the GPU and make the transformations there

Comment: Sure, but I am not doing the transformation in pandas, `dot` comes from numpy and then I just store it in a pandas dataframe in the end.

Comment: What @BPL wrote is true.  Since you are asking about efficiency, it is best to perform all of the operation in numpy.  There is overhead attached to creating a dataframe; it is much more efficient to keep all of the data in a numpy array and avoid the cost of pushing and pulling into additional data structures.

Comment: @James I understand this, and I am not doing the operation in pandas; it is being done in numpy. The nature of my library is that it has to be re-stored in pandas dataframes regardless.

Comment: In `numpy` reshape and transpose are fast.  The matrix product tools are `dot`, `transdot`, `einsum` and `matmul` (`@`).  For simple cases `dot` is fastest, since it uses optimized libraries.

Comment: @hpaulj ok so basically, from a numpy point of view, I cannot get much faster?

Comment: As hpaulj says, transpose and reshape are not building intermediate arrays and are not costing you extra operations because of the size of your array. And `dot` is as efficient as it gets, since it's probably dispatched to BLAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should never touch a dataframe until you are done with your transformations.

```
a = np.array([
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
    ])

rotmat = np.array([
        [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
        [  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
        [ -1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]
    ])

a.reshape(3, 3, -1).dot(rotmat).reshape(-1, 9)

array([[ 0.,  1.,  0., -1.,  1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  0.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(3, 3, -1).dot(rotmat).reshape(-1, 9))
df
```

[image]